# Is NServiceBus a good fit for cross platform integration?

Tags: messaging, nservicebus

Is NServiceBus a good fit if you want to integrate .NET applications with other applications written in languages like python or even php on Linux?

Of course you would have to replace MSMQ with another queuing solution like ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ. I already read that this is possible. But is it actually feasible and stable?

Besides that, how much magic does NServiceBus implement for basic scenarios like pub/sub with durable subscriptions, which you would have to re-implement in the other languages.

If NServiceBus is not a good fit, what would you recommend instead?

Answer (score 5):

Alebo, I believe NServiceBus is a good fit for connecting components from other platforms. We create "adapters" that bridge the c#-centric bus with other technologies. We've got one that takes command as SOAP calls, another that looks for files in a directory, another that accepts POP3. Then, we simply put those messages on the bus. We do the same thing with published events going the other direction. The messages are just XML files that any language can create and consume.

It works great, and we didn't have to change out the MSMQ provider.

Comment: How do you get, say, Java to interoperate with MSMQ? Just curious. Thanks

Comment: Hugh, we don't have Java interact with directly with MSMQ. We create a service (call it an adapter) in C# that exposes a Web service. That Web service listens for XML messages and puts them on the bus. The Java code can then cal that Web service. For events, we expose a Web service that implements a long polling technique. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, thanks for clearing that up. I just wondered because I know from experience the pain of integrating java and msmq. In your solution you would not be able to handle transactional messaging from java to msmq because you would be forced to use basicHttpBindings on you web service. Or am I incorrect?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Eric. I was more thinking about using the queuing system as a common denominator, that all interacting systems directly talk to, instead of using adapters. That's why I mentioned using another queuing system. Most of our systems are implemented with php or phython. Just the new ones are using .NET.

Comment: If you site are using php and you have application running in .net. You can use (PServiceBus: pservicebus.codeplex.com) which gives you a javascript api that can pub/sub. So it means you will be able to publish message from your .net application and receive it on your php website using the javascript api that is provided. An example of using javascript with the ESB is the JS Chat App listed on the sample.